# Change css for a div inside currently active div (on pageload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page which users get to by clicking through an ebook. When they click a link it takes them to a product on the page depending on the link so it looks like

> example.com/#product1
>
> example.com/#product6
>
> example.com/#product15,
>
> etc...

The page already scrolls to that part of the page using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: jQuery(window.location.hash).offset().top-150
      }, 900, 'swing');
});
```

I have another div within the `#product1` div called `#amazonbutton` with a style of `display:none`.

```
<div id="product1" class="product">
  <a href="link">
    <div id="amazonbutton"><img src="amazonbuttonz" />
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

This is because it's a "go to amazon" button hidden for all items except the currently selected div. So basically, the button should display for the :active div while staying in its original state (hidden) for all inactive divs.

How can I change this with jquery?

I have this bit of code which is incomplete and I'm stuck:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('amazonbutton').each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).attr('href')  ===  window.location.href) {
      jQuery(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Better if you could create a similar demo here, or on JSFiddle.

Comment: can you explain briefly and specifically on what you're trying to achieve and what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is a cool thing called `document.activeElement` . It is a read only property that tracks the current active element.

```
$('.yourdivclass').hide();
$(document.activeElement).show();
```

You can activate a element by `.focus()` `.activate()`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you looped the amazonbutton, in your code i saw that it wasn't a link. So you can't check the `attr href`. I guess that you want to check the href of amazonbutton's parent. Secondly, amazonbutton in your loop is a class or id? You must add `.` or `#` to it. The code could be:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#amazonbutton').each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).parent().attr('href')  ===  window.location.href) {
      jQuery(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```